# write Dockerfile for implement asp.net framework MVC project with Mono on docker in Linux Container

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linux, docker, mono, dockerfile

I want to launch ASP.net MVC framework with Mono on Linux platform in Docker container.

I can pull mono and restore packages and build project but I cannot run the project with mono.

I uploaded a simple MVC project (aspnetapp2) on this link

https://github.com/Hatef-Rostamkhani/asp.net.mvc.mono.dockerfile

There is a PowerShell script called RunDocker.NetFramwork.ps1 to launch docker against the project's `.dockerfile`.

```
FROM mono:latest AS build-env

WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./

RUN msbuild -t:restore

COPY . .

RUN nuget restore aspnetapp2.csproj -SolutionDirectory ../ -Verbosity normal

RUN msbuild

CMD [ "mono", "aspnetapp2.dll" ]
```

Comment: what goes wrong? Error logs?